# When editing an embedded google doc, a blanc drive picker is shown when wanting to insert a image

Tags: html, iframe, google-docs, google-docs-api

This case is about embedding a document in an iframe on a webpage. The document loads correctly. The end user should be able to edit the document. But when the end user wants to add an image by clicking on insert > image, he gets the a blanc popup.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/101KCoVpNM1QTXIILePLDE0GSPbrb5LGidnbF0iFSEos/edit" width="600px" height="600px" />
</body>

</html>
```

[selecting insert > image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fhNL.png)

[the blanc drive picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w4Ye.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure that you are inserting a supported image file type as enumerated in [Importing to Google Docs types](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk18wzxhzdk19). For images, you can use the following:

- JPEG
- PNG
- GIF
- BMP
- PDF

Next, you may want to check the following [forum threads](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/H5v5aSjxQ_U) wherein the required settings were given and also the guidelines on how you can properly insert images.

- [Insert Image -> just blank (does not show, except in print preview)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/H5v5aSjxQ_U)
- [Insert Pictures Do Not Preview or Print Out](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=23404)

Lastly, you may want to also check the response in this [related post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21087/how-to-embed-pictures-from-google-docs-in-new-interface) wherein it was suggested that you may publish the document as a web page and get the image URL from the source of the resulting web page since Google Docs inserted images doesn't have a URL that users could get from the edit view.

Comment: Hi Teyam, thank you for your answer. But this case is about editing a google doc in a webpage. The code I provided is minimal code to reproduce the problem. The google doc shows on the page, they can edit the text, but they cannot insert an image because the popup doesn't show. This case has nothing to do with the image not showing on the doc. They already cannot insert it in the first place.